# Is gas solubility independent of pressure?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, ideal-gas

My physical chemistry textbook poses this question:

> Prove the statement that an alternative way to express Henry’s law of gas solubility is to say that the volume of gas that dissolves in a fixed volume of solution is independent of pressure at a given temperature.

My proof is thus:

$P_2 = Kx_2$, where $P_2$ is the partial pressure of a solute, $K$ is the Henry's law constant, and $x_2$ is the mole fraction of solute dissolved in solution. By the ideal gas law,

$\frac{n_2RT}{V} = Kx_2 \rightarrow V = \frac{n_2RT}{Kx_2}$.

Therefore, V depends on temperature, not  pressure. Regardless of if my proof's correct, I'm missing part of the picture here. Intuitively, I want believe increasing pressure leads to an increase in dissolved gas. If you have a beaker of water and some gas in a metal box, and then you decrease the volume of that container, like a piston, at constant temperature, wouldn't more gas dissolve?

Comment: read Dr Pippiks answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You state, it seems that, logically, "increasing pressure leads to an increase in dissolved gas." Your logic is **not** wrong... an increased **mass** of gas dissolves.

The confusion is because here, Henry's law is stated in terms of the **volume** of gas. Since increasing pressure makes the gas occupy less volume, it has higher density. As a hypothetical example:

- At STP, i.e., 1 atm, Gas X has a density  ${1 g/l}$. It dissolves in water at the ratio ${1 l_{Gas X}/l_{H2O}}$, so 1 gram of Gas X is absorbed in a liter of water.
- At 10 atm, Gas X has a density  ${10 g/l}$. Still, just one one liter dissolves in a liter of water. But that one liter is **10 grams** of Gas X at that higher pressure, so ten times the *mass* of Gas X dissolves in a liter of water.

Of course, this assumes a perfect gas, and that there is no chemical reaction with the liquid. For example, [$\ce{CO2}$ in water may form clathrates](https://geo2.unibe.ch/diamond/DiamonduAkinfiev.FPE.2003.pdf), throwing off a linear relation. The reference cited provides corrections to Henry's law to account for empirical results.

Answer (score 1):

Let n be the number of moles of solute dissolved in $n_{solvent}$ moles of solvent (in dilute solution).  Then, $$x=\frac{n}{n_{solvent}}$$So, $$P=\frac{n}{n_{solvent}}K$$or$$K=n_{solvent}\frac{P}{n}=n_{solvent}\frac{V}{RT}$$So, the volume of ideal gas at temperature T that dissolves is $$V=\frac{KRT}{n_{solvent}}$$

Comment: Yes, from the OP, I believe that is understood. However, the question from that intuitive approach implies concern about the *increased mass*, rather than *constant volume*.